# Team Foundation Server won't build because nuget packages dont exist

Tags: c#, tfs

So i created a new solution. Added all my projects to it. Downloaded all the nuget packages.

I checked it all in. On another pc I pulled the solution down. I hit build and I get a tonne of errors relating to not being able to find the dll of the packages.

So I set automatically download packages if they're missing. Still nothing works. Why is this?

When I Enabled it, it came back with an error saying that it could not modify the projects because they were locked.... This is why I want to re-enable the context menu item that allows me to enable nuget to automatically download missing packages.

Comment: Have you set "Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build"?

Comment: In nuget config set <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />

Comment: @Donal yes to the first comment, where is the nuget config?

Comment: all that has been done

Comment: should be in your project folder

Comment: I done all that. Doesnt work

Comment: is there any way to reenable the contxt menu button "Allow NuGet to download ......"??

Comment: Do you see the option "Enable NuGet Package Restore"?

Comment: See here: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: Also - you should not check in the stuff NuGet has downloaded.

Comment: I tried the enable, it didnt work

Comment: Have a go at this: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: What version of VS are you using? Did you check in the packages.config? There are a variety of possible issues, but we need more details to really troubleshoot.

Comment: VS2013, everything has been checked in!

Comment: @No1_Melman probackpacker is correct - there could be a number of issues here.

Comment: Excellent, so how far have we got to finding the issue?

Comment: @Donal I've tried the command line `nuget.exe restore` and it says that the packages already exist!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is I checked in all the packages. They all got download onto the other machine, that's why NuGet was saying that I already had the packages.

I solved this by going into the solution directory (physical path) and deleted the packages folder.

Then I built the project, and true to NuGets word it downloaded all the packages again. It also succeeded in building the application, no errors!

I would advise that if you are going to enable the NuGet package restore that you check out the solution first, once you're done check in the solution!